# Check if user is logged in, inside php file in template directory

Tags: authentication

I have a php file in my template directory which generates some data from a database. I only want this data to be accessable for my wordpress users.

I tried by using this line of code but it gives me an error saying "headers already sent".

What is wrong? Or is there any other way to solve this?

```
<?php

 require_once('../../../wp-blog-header.php');

 if (is_user_logged_in())
 {

    echo "hello world";

 }
 else
 {
    echo "You do not have access to this resource!";
 }
?>
```

Comment: why not use `TEMPLATEPATH` constant?

Comment: The code is working for me with no error. I suppose a problem is within other parts of your code. Try to "google" for how to solve a "headers already sent" problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the file is in your theme directory, Wordpress may not want the user to "directly" access it. Why not create a Page in wordpress, assign a Template Name to your PHP page and then assign that to the new page created in wordpress. For example, you would have a new page called "Members Only" and its template is "php-page-located-in-theme". Then, in the code, you don't have to call the blog header, just simply wrap the entire page in your "Is user logged in" if else statement.

Example:

```
<?php
Template Name: php-page-located-in-theme

get_header();

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
    /*PHP Generated Content Goes Here*/
} else {
    echo 'You cannot access this page.';
}
get_sidebar();
get_footer(); 
?>
```

Comment: You are wrong, the path is correct. He said the file is located in his theme directory _root/wp-content/themes/theme/file.php_

Comment: Ah! Stupid me, will amend my answer then.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
require_once('../../../wp-blog-header.php');
global $wpdb;
global $current_user,$user_ID;
get_currentuserinfo();
if($user_ID=="")
{
echo "You do not have access to this resource!";
}
else
{
    echo "hello world";
}
?>
You can use global variable global $current_user,$user_ID for checking user is login or not.
```